# Importing users that will be installed by programs

Tags: passwd

I am migrating from an old Ubuntu 10.04 server to a different machine, upgrading to 14.04 at the same time.

One of my tasks is to migrate the users, so I have exported a list of users with UID > 1000 on the old machine and then appended that list to the list on the new machine

```
cat userlist >> /etc/passwd
```

Same for `/etc/shadow`.

I noticed a few users that were probably not created manually but are the result of the installation of a program. In my case, these users are `vmail` and `spamd`.

Now I wonder, whether importing those users before installing the program may cause any issues. Should I

1. install `dovecot` and `spamassassin` first, then import the users, check the result with `pwck` and delete the duplicate
2. import the users, then install `dovecot` and `spamassassin` as it will reuse the existing user and not cause issues
3. something completely different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not cause problems.

Creating users from random software is done with a check where is tested  if the user already exists.

And there is a better method for creating users. The command `newusers {file}` where {file} is in the format

```
loginname:password:uid:gid:comment:home_dir:shell
```

(and yes, that is the password file format) will create all the users in that file where existing users are skipped. It will also create the home directories (where yours will not).

See the [newusers manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/newusers) for some tips and tricks (the password field is something to have a look at though since it wants plain text and not encrypted passwords).

Comment: It seems `newusers` needs plain text passwords, but I only have encrypted passwords from /etc/shadow

Comment: @ThomasWeller I would avoid that issue: have the users retype their password (and call it a security measure ;-)).