# Creating a user without its account being disabled

Tags: command-line, users, adduser

Is there a way to create a new standard user, who can log in immediately? When I create users through a shell script, the users do get created, but they are disabled. Is there are way to create them so that they can log in without additional actions?

I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what do you mean they are disabled? what command are you using to create them?

Comment: @Zanna I think his using the old `useradd` where no password is given to the user hence the user is disable until a password is set...

Comment: seems likely @George :) if so question is sure to be a duplicate. Right now it's just unclear

Comment: Pass in the `-p user_password` option in the script that should solve the problem

Comment: Also saw this neat trick `echo username:new_password | chpasswd` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script. Like this one as it encrypts the password

Comment: If you are creating accounts programatically, you should consider using the `newusers` command: see for example [Importing users that will be installed by programs](https://askubuntu.com/a/719202/178692)

Comment: @Zanna right now I use `adduser` And what I mean is that you can't log in into the newly created account, until you manually enable it

Answer (score 0):

Since you can create a user then your script works, now use the `chpasswd` tool to create a password for your users as **without this, they won't be able to sign in** after creation.

```
echo username:username | chpasswd
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script